# Code Optimization in XML blogger template

Tags: javascript, xml, performance, blogger

Im trying to develop a blogger template and I need help to optimize my code, now I have some problem with this code in the xml:

```
function labelthumbs(e) {
document.write('<ul class="' + outerclass + '">');
for (var t = 0; t < numposts; t++) {
    var r, i = e.feed.entry[t],
        n = i.title.$t,
        l = i.category[0].term,
        l2 = i.category[1].term;
    if (t == e.feed.entry.length) break;
    for (var o = 0; o < i.link.length; o++)
        if ("alternate" == i.link[o].rel) {
            r = i.link[o].href;
            break
        }
    var u;
    try {
        u = i.media$thumbnail.url
    } catch (p) {
        s = i.content.$t, a = s.indexOf("<img"), b = s.indexOf('src="', a), c = s.indexOf('"', b + 5), d = s.substr(b + 5, c - b - 5), u = -1 != a && -1 != b && -1 != c && "" != d ? d : "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-pmtmCl8EbTI/UoY33J0Dp9I/AAAAAAAAAAA/fbchARjKIDg/s500-c/grey.gif"
    }
    var m = i.published.$t,
        v = m.substring(0, 4),
        g = m.substring(5, 7),
        h = m.substring(8, 10),
        f = new Array;
        f[1] = "January", 
        f[2] = "February", 
        f[3] = "March", 
        f[4] = "April", 
        f[5] = "May", 
        f[6] = "June", 
        f[7] = "July", 
        f[8] = "August", 
        f[9] = "September", 
        f[10] = "October", 
        f[11] = "November", 
        f[12] = "December";
        var A = f[parseInt(g, 10)] + " " + h + ", " + v;
        if (l == "pc")
        {
        document.write(starttag + "<" + intag + ' class="post">'), 
        document.write('<div class="post-media"><div class="image-wrap"><img src="' + u.replace("/s72-c/", "/s400-p/") + '" alt="' + n + '"/></div></div><div class="post-body">'), "featured-slider" == outerclass &&
          document.write('<span class="cat"><a style="background:red" href="/search/label/' + l + '">' + l + '</a><a href="/search/label/' + l2 + '">' + l2 + '</a></span><div class="post-title"><h4><a href="' + r + '">' + n + '</a></h4></div><div class="post-meta"><span class="post-date">' + A + "</span></div></div>"), "sub-menu" == outerclass && 
        document.write('<div class="post-title"><h2><a href="' + r + '">' + n + '</a></h2></div><span class="post-date">' + A + "</span></div>"),
        document.write("</" + intag + ">" + endtag)
        }
        else if (l == "ps4")
        {
        document.write(starttag + "<" + intag + ' class="post">'), 
        document.write('<div class="post-media"><div class="image-wrap"><img src="' + u.replace("/s72-c/", "/s400-p/") + '" alt="' + n + '"/></div></div><div class="post-body">'), "featured-slider" == outerclass &&
          document.write('<span class="cat"><a style="background:blue" href="/search/label/' + l + '">' + l + '</a><a href="/search/label/' + l2 + '">' + l2 + '</a></span><div class="post-title"><h4><a href="' + r + '">' + n + '</a></h4></div><div class="post-meta"><span class="post-date">' + A + "</span></div></div>"), "sub-menu" == outerclass && 
        document.write('<div class="post-title"><h2><a href="' + r + '">' + n + '</a></h2></div><span class="post-date">' + A + "</span></div>"),
        document.write("</" + intag + ">" + endtag)
        }
        else if (l == "xbox")
        {
        document.write(starttag + "<" + intag + ' class="post">'), 
        document.write('<div class="post-media"><div class="image-wrap"><img src="' + u.replace("/s72-c/", "/s400-p/") + '" alt="' + n + '"/></div></div><div class="post-body">'), "featured-slider" == outerclass &&
          document.write('<span class="cat"><a style="background:green" href="/search/label/' + l + '">' + l + '</a><a href="/search/label/' + l2 + '">' + l2 + '</a></span><div class="post-title"><h4><a href="' + r + '">' + n + '</a></h4></div><div class="post-meta"><span class="post-date">' + A + "</span></div></div>"), "sub-menu" == outerclass && 
        document.write('<div class="post-title"><h2><a href="' + r + '">' + n + '</a></h2></div><span class="post-date">' + A + "</span></div>"),
        document.write("</" + intag + ">" + endtag)
        }
        else if (l == "wii")
        {
        document.write(starttag + "<" + intag + ' class="post">'), 
        document.write('<div class="post-media"><div class="image-wrap"><img src="' + u.replace("/s72-c/", "/s400-p/") + '" alt="' + n + '"/></div></div><div class="post-body">'), "featured-slider" == outerclass &&
          document.write('<span class="cat"><a style="background:grey" href="/search/label/' + l + '">' + l + '</a><a href="/search/label/' + l2 + '">' + l2 + '</a></span><div class="post-title"><h4><a href="' + r + '">' + n + '</a></h4></div><div class="post-meta"><span class="post-date">' + A + "</span></div></div>"), "sub-menu" == outerclass && 
        document.write('<div class="post-title"><h2><a href="' + r + '">' + n + '</a></h2></div><span class="post-date">' + A + "</span></div>"),
        document.write("</" + intag + ">" + endtag)
        }
        else
        {
        document.write(starttag + "<" + intag + ' class="post">'), 
        document.write('<div class="post-media"><div class="image-wrap"><img src="' + u.replace("/s72-c/", "/s400-p/") + '" alt="' + n + '"/></div></div><div class="post-body">'), "featured-slider" == outerclass &&
          document.write('<span class="cat"><a style="background:yellow" href="/search/label/' + l + '">' + l + '</a><a href="/search/label/' + l2 + '">' + l2 + '</a></span><div class="post-title"><h4><a href="' + r + '">' + n + '</a></h4></div><div class="post-meta"><span class="post-date">' + A + "</span></div></div>"), "sub-menu" == outerclass && 
        document.write('<div class="post-title"><h2><a href="' + r + '">' + n + '</a></h2></div><span class="post-date">' + A + "</span></div>"),
        document.write("</" + intag + ">" + endtag)
        }
    }
    document.write("</ul>")
};
```

Is it any way to perform a better conditional use? not sure to put the if inside the document.write, after all the condition is just for one variable.
You can check my test blog at: http://pruebaxweb.blogspot.pe/
what I want to get is that the posts with "PC, ps4, xbox, etc" tags shows first and the "action, shooter, rpg, arcade" tags shows after.
If anyone can help me I'll appreciate it so much

Thanks guys

Comment: Better way for a conditional javascript `switch` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch , but why don't you construct the whole thing with blogger syntax/xml. Are you using blogger API? or ... ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too broad, however it may be a better fit on codereview.stackexchange.com . Please read their help pages before posting to make sure your question is on-topic there.